# Solving for matrix system using least squares quadratic

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratics, matrix-equations, least-squares

So I'm given the following coordinates below and I'm asked to set up a matrix system to solve for the least squares expressions.

I have the first question right, and I have matrix A of the second question correct. I'm a little stumped on how I would find the matrix for b though? I know b generally represents the y coordinates, but since there is a 2nd degree I'm not exactly sure what to do. Am I supposed to substitute coordinates into some sort of formula? I would appreciate any help!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question, I believe the $y$ values will be the same as in the first problem, i.e. $b=-9,8, \ldots$.  The change is only on the left hand side with the $\beta$ and $x$ part of the problem.

I hope this helps.